# find missing column header in excel using python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to find if all the required column names are present in the excel using python.
for example:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3
Val1    Val4    Val6
Val2    val5    Val7
```

I want to know if `header4` is present or not

I use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
path=C:\Req_file\excel_file

xl = pd.Excelfile(path)

for name in xl.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xl, name)
my_cols = [Header1, Header2,Header3,Header4]
print(df[my_cols])
```

It generates a

> Keyerror: [header4] not in index

I would like to know is it possible to do with "if" statement.
I want to generate an error message on the frame, but I get only in the terminal.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `df.columns` will list the names of the column headers: you can test if your column of interest is present: `if "my_column" in df.columns:`.

Comment: If you are trying to generate an error message if the header is missing, it is more pythonic to use `try:` over `if:`. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/06/29/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/

Comment: @Dan: absolutely true, with the caveat that if you have to do this for a dozen required columns, with optional intermediate code in between, there is no single point now where the existence is checked. Unless you perform a no-op try-except: `try: df[required_columns]; except KeyError:`. Potentially better is even to just let the KeyError bubble up to the user.

Comment: `try: df[required_columns]; except KeyError:` looks correct to me. I like the set solution you posted, but in this instance your `try:` code makes more sense to me. I think you should add it to your answer maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check that *all* required column headers are present, you can use sets, and use the `columns` attribute of a dataframe:

```
if set(required_columns) <= set(df.columns):
    print("all required columns are there")
```

---

If you need to find the missing required columns, use the set difference, with the required columns first (so that additional columns are ignored):

```
missing = set(required_columns) - set(df.columns)
```

and combine the two as follows:

```
missing = set(required_columns) - set(df.columns)
if missing:
    print("Missing required columns:", missing)
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can print the missing column header from the my_columns which are not present in df.columns?

Comment: Probably `print(set(my_columns) - set(df.columns))` will do.

Comment: Thank u all. I got want I need.

Answer (score 0):

link this:

```
In [5]: data=pd.DataFrame([["Abao","man"],["Tom","man"]],columns=["name","sex"])

In [6]: data
Out[6]: 
   name  sex
0  Abao  man
1   Tom  man

In [7]: data.columns 
Out[7]: Index(['name', 'sex'], dtype='object')

In [8]: "age" in data.columns
Out[8]: False

In [9]: "sex" in data.columns
Out[9]: True
```